# How to get all users third-party sign-in events in Google Workspace?

Tags: google-api, access-token, google-workspace, google-account

I want to get all the sign up & sign in with Google events of my Google Workspace users using API.

I can see the Tokens activity from my Google Workspace admin account, under the audit log (https://admin.google.com/u/5/ac/reporting/audit/token), but it's limited to first sign ups, and doesn't show any of the following sign in events of my users.

Is there any way to see all the events related to third parties sign ins / sign ups of my users? is there any place that lists the summary of all of the third parties linked to users in my organization?

Answer (score 2):

As far as a summary, you can retrieve a list of applications authorized by your users using the [Directory API tokens.list method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/list).

Unfortunately when it comes to OIDC sign in events, there currently is no way to see when users are logging into a 3rd party application. You will see activity events for tools accessing Google APIs, but not for login.

I guess you could use [tokens.delete](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/delete) to revoke access, making the users re-authorize to log in again (which will be logged). But that's a rather heavy handed approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found what you're after:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-tokens
You can use this api call to retrieve all authorization events for third party applications.

The general format of such requests is below (parameters are surrounded by a double asterix)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all
/applications/token?endTime=**end date**&startTime=**start date**
&maxResults=**maximum number of events returned on a response page**
```

Hopefully this gets you the info you want. I don't have access to a google admin account myself so I can't test this api call.